# Благодать низошла или благодать снизошла на кого-то?

Tags: грамотность, семантика

Как правильно: ***благодать низошла*** на кого-то или ***благодать снизошла*** на кого-то?

Comment: In Russian or in Church Slavonic?

Comment: @Quassnoi let's assume that by default it's always about Russian

Comment: Of course in Russian.

Comment: Все зависит от контекста.И от речевого стиля, который вы хотите передать. В поэзии, философии "низошла" очень даже к месту.

Comment: Не очень представляю контекст, в котором благодать нисходит. Приведите пример, пожалуйста. По умолчанию - конечно же, **благодать снизошла**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern Russian, *снисходить* means "to condescend, to deign", so if you're about to compose a neutral phrase in modern Russian, meaning "grace (has) descended", you should probably be using *благодать низошла*.

However, its original meaning in Church Slavonic is "to descend" and using Church Slavonic is a common way to give your Russian text grand style. So if that's your purpose, then you can use either word.

Comment: Not just Church Slavonic. Before XX century, "благодать снизошла" was perfectly valid in regular Russian.

Comment: @Alexander: *снизойти* is a Church Slavonic loanword which has shifted its meaning in Russian. _благодать снизошла_ is just as valid in modern Russian as any other loaned expression: *что поделать, се ля ви; всё будет ол райт; ой, цо то бендзе* are all valid regular Russian, you can hear them from people who don't speak any French or English or Polish and don't intend to. Church Slavonic is close enough to Russian and has had such a great influence on it that many Russian speakers treat that as some kind of "obsolete Russian", but it's not, it's as foreign as all the languages listed above.